# why does the below code returns NullPointerException

Tags: java, autoboxing

The code below throws a `NullPointerException` but I don't understand why, the object is not null.

```
public class A{
    int GetValue()
    {
        return (true ? null : 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        A obj= new A();
        obj.GetValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: What object? You mean the null `Integer` reference you're unboxing to return an `int`?

Answer (score 3):

Because it is `unboxing` a `null` into `int`

```
(true ? null : 0); // returns null always
```

The return value is an `int` and converting a `null` into `int` throws an `NPE`

when your method returns a primitive you need to make sure that the value is never `null`. You can fix it by returning `Integer`

```
Integer GetValue() // allows nulls
{
    return (true ? null : 0);
}
```

But then again callers might fail

```
int x = GetValue(); //fails
```

returning an [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) would be a better fix.